# Unwanted bytes in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

**Summary:**

I am trying to pre-process a text to do classification or topic modelling afterwards. The problem is while pre-processing, there are some issues with encoding I couldn't resolve, encoding is really a troublesome topic.

**Description:**

The given string is taken from an excel file,

```
s = "  GEÇİCİ  \n\t"
```

Now when I try to apply some replacements and tokenization to this string I face an issue where the string becomes,

```
print(re.sub(r'[^a-zıöüşçğ.,\']', ' ', s.lower()))
# '  geçi ci     '
```

The result shouldn't be separated like that, it ruins my tokenization process. Then I tried case-insensitive approach, which worked well.

```
print(re.sub(r'[^a-zıöüşçğ.,\']', ' ', s, flags=re.I).lower())
# '  geçi̇ci̇    '
```

Now to understand what went wrong, I try to encode the original string into "utf-8", this is fine,

```
print(s.encode("utf-8"))
# b'  GE\xc3\x87\xc4\xb0C\xc4\xb0  \n\t'
```

But when I try to encode it after using lower(), there the problem lies,

```
print(s.lower().encode("utf-8"))
# b'  ge\xc3\xa7i\xcc\x87ci\xcc\x87  \n\t'
```

to compare with the expected result

```
print("geçici".encode("utf-8"))
# b'ge\xc3\xa7ici'
```

**Question:**

Where do those two *b'\xcc\x87'* come from ?

I remember having come across with a similar problem like this in C#. There was a method like `ToLowerInvariant` which bypassed such a problem. Looked for such parameter that I can pass to lower but nothing came up.

Comment: your expected result is wrong: you're assuming that `"İ".lower() == "i"` (regular "i")

Comment: @bobrobbob Shouldn't it be like that, what is the correct way of doing it then ?

Comment: of course not. upper "i" is "I" not "İ"

Comment: That's what I am asking actually, how can I avoid this to make `"İ".lower() == "i"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those two b'\xcc\x87' are lower `İ`. if you want to get rid of them, update your regex with it: `r'[^a-zıi̇öüşçğ.,\']'`. i̇  may look like regular lower `i` bit it's not (note the double dotted pattern when it's not in a code block)

here a picture of different variants from my text editor: dotless ı, dotless i̇ with dot, regular i

[image: variant of i]

Comment: How so ? Isn't `i` already included in `a-z` ? Am I making a mistake in regex then ?

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer because you led me to the correct way. So instead of using `lower` directly, I replaced the problematic chars with the corresponding lower ones, after that I applied `lower`.